# Create a rails 3 plugin with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, ruby-on-rails-plugins

The question explains itself...

I wanna test a new rails plugin with rspec, are there any specific generators, gems?

I used `rails g plugin blabla` and I got an error on rspec generator: `error  rspec [not found]`.

Answer (score 1):

FYI - there is an open github issue about this: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/#issue/258.

Comment: Good to know ! found strange that I didn't find anyone with a tutorial about this.